# Sphinx change table of contents HTML

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, python-sphinx, tableofcontents

I'm working on theming my documentation, and I'm trying to get sphinx to add a class to the `<ul>` elements of the Table of Contents. Unfortunately, it looks like the HTML is generated just the same as any other list.

Is there a way to add a class to the TOC?

The class that I want to add (fyi) is `nav nav-tabs nav-stacked`; I'm using a bootstrap theme.

**Update:** my current hack is to override `localtoc.html` template to have

```
{{ toc|replace("<ul>", "<ul class='nav nav-tabs nav-stacked'>") }}
```

but it feels ugly...

Comment: There is a :class: parameter you can list before the element, or rst-class. http://sphinx-doc.org/rest.html#id2

Comment: But the element is created by sphinx automatically, not by me ...

Comment: Maybe post-process elements in injected JavaScript snippet would be the easiest choice?

Comment: Ooh that feels hackier than my current solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TOCs are converted to HTML separately and then inserted into the document, without letting you control it. Checkout the `render_partial` method of `sphinx.builds.html.StandaloneHTMLBuilder`.

Your hack is the easiest method, the other option is to subclass `StandaloneHTMLBuilder` and override `render_partial` to control the docutils' `HTMLWriter`.

Comment: it would be nice for sphinx to support this better :(